# Does Angular 4 supports PWA

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add `@angular/pwa` to my Angular 4 project, it's my very first time with PWAs. Its giving error :

> The specified command add is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.

Is this because of Angular version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add the pwa library using `ng add` command in Angular 4 because `add` is introduced in Angular 6.

You have to add it using this command

```
npm i @angular/pwa
```

Comment: Yes this command runs successfully. I'm trying to follow this tutorial
https://medium.com/@cdeniz/transforming-an-existing-angular-application-into-a-progressive-web-app-d48869ba391f

So, after I installed, the rest steps would be same or again there would be some different steps to create SW and manifest files?